# How to vertically align images inside a list

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

`vertical-align` has always given me problems in the past and once again I'm met with a problem that I don't know how to solve.

I have this html:

```
<ul id="council-slider">
  <li class="col-md-12" style="display: block">
    <img src="somesource" />
    <div class="council-spacer"></div>
    <p>text content goes here</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#council-slider {
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style: none;
    min-height: 300px;
    max-height: 400px;
}

#council-slider li img {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 5px;
}

.council-spacer {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}

#council-slider li p {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

I want to be able to vertically align the image in the middle. The text is multiple lines that wrapped so using `line-height` will not work in this situation. Also the images can have varying heights.

There are multiple list items; I just used one in the example to simplify and reduce the html.

Comment: Kindly post your CSS code too.

Comment: Put HTML and CSS in a https://jsfiddle.net/  even better!

Comment: @CodeBlend even worse - you should always post your code in the question before relying on a fiddle to display the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read up on where the `vertical-align` property has the ability to be applied.

Quoting from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

> The vertical-align CSS property specifies the vertical alignment of an **inline** or **table-cell** box.

Since your element is not being displayed as either `inline` or `table-cell` `vertical-align: middle;` will not do you any good here.

You can, however, set your `<div>` styling to `display: table-cell;` and then `vertical-align: middle`

***Alternatively***, this can be achieved with CSS3 as hars pointed out, just make sure your user's browsers support CSS3

```
.valign-middle {
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   Transform: translateY (-50%);
}
```

The way this works -

- Set position relative to the parent/container (i.e. `<li>` in your case)
- Move the image that you want to vertically align, down 50% of the container height
- Move the image up 50% of the height of the image

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to your img as below.

```
.verticallyCenter {
  position: relative;
  top:50%;
  Transform:translateY (-50%);}
```

Refer  [This](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your actual css code it is hard to say, but you should use `vertical-align: middle` for all objects that you want to align and you may need to change the display of your paragraph to `display: table-cell`.

Answer (score 0):

Will be easier using flexbox: `display: flex;` and `align-items: center;`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tinmarin60/ew8rb9f7/1/)

```
#council-slider {
list-style: none;
}

#council-slider li{
    display: flex;
    margin: 10px 0;
    align-items: center;
}
.council-spacer {
    width: 20px;
}
```